# What to do about old alpha/beta questions?

Tags: discussion

For some reason we always collect "How do I get/install foobar beta!" type questions, which are probably too localized (useful for what, a few weeks at most?).

They do seem to provide a service to people when some new snazzy thing comes out and people want to mess with it, so I think that's cool.

However, check out when I do a search for "[firefox beta](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=firefox%20beta)". A good deal of these can be blown away and the internet would be a better place.

... or is it one of those "they're marked answered, they helped someone at the time, they're not bothering anyone, so let them be, go find better things to do."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A good deal of these can be blown away and the internet would be a better place.

I think you have answered your own question, and it's certainly what I would advise... :)

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to make sure that was ok before I flagged a ton of stuff that might affect people's reputation, etc.